# NPM publish produces FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-publish

I'm trying to publish an npm package. But I am getting this error upon giving the command `npm publish`.

JS stacktrace

```
Security context: 0000013BB24A57C1 <JSObject>

 1: _writeGeneric [net.js:765] [bytecode=0000017102067151 offset=351](this=000000B0CC896439 <TLSSocket map = 000003E535A4BF21>,writev=0000009710482371 <true>
,data=0000030A8AB92831 <JSArray[2]>,encoding=0000009710482431 <String[0]: >,cb=000000B0CC896CA9 <JSBoundFunction (BoundTargetFunction 0000019FF9638929)>)

2: connect [net.js:729] [bytecode=0000013622F65119 offset=29](this=000000B0CC8...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

 1: node_module_register

 2: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory

 3: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory

 4: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString

 5: v8::internal::Smi::SmiPrint

 6: v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts

 7: v8::String::WriteUtf8

 8: v8_inspector::V8InspectorClient::currentTimeMS

 9: v8_inspector::V8InspectorClient::currentTimeMS

10: uv_loop_size

11: v8::internal::wasm::SignatureMap::Find

12: v8::internal::Builtins::CallableFor

13: v8::internal::Builtins::CallableFor

14: v8::internal::Builtins::CallableFor

15: 000001E9D12843C1
```

I have also tried including this "--max_old_space_size=8192" in AppData -> npm -> ng.cmd

When I tried giving this command

```
node --max_old_space_size=2000  filename
```

I have many files to publish but this command allows only one file.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: can you include a link to your project on Github or wherever it is?

Comment: It's a private repository and I realized that the error is because I was trying to publish a file which is 500MB. So, is there any solution to publish such large files to npm?

Comment: which file is that big? You might need to use a CDN. I think Github allows for up to 2 GB for git repo btw.

Comment: google says: "If your repository exceeds 1GB, you might receive a polite email from support requesting that you reduce the size of the repository to bring it back down under 1GB. In addition, we place a strict limit of files exceeding 100 MB in size."